# Update (CRUD) code doesnt have error but its doesnt work either

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

i need help with my code. I make a process to edit a data (update) in my CRUD.

This is my Update CRUD code in my controller :

```
public function update() {
$paket = array(
    'nama' => Input::get('nama'),
    'jumlah_user' => Input::get('jumlah_user'),
    'tanggal_mulai' => Input::get('tanggal_mulai'),
    'tanggal_terakhir' => Input::get('tanggal_terakhir')
  );
  DB::table('paket')->where('id','=',Input::get('id'))->update($paket);
  return Redirect::route('paket.index')->with('message','berhasil mengedit data');
}
```

and this is code in my edit form:

```
{{Form::open(array('url'=>'admin/prosesedit','method'=>'post','charset'=>'utf-8'))}}
{{Form::text("nama",$paket->nama,['placeholder'=>'Nama Paket','autocomplete'=>'off','required'])}}
{{Form::text("jumlah_user",$paket->jumlah_user,['placeholder'=>'Jumlah User','autocomplete'=>'off','required'])}}
{{Form::text("tanggal_mulai",$paket->tanggal_mulai,['placeholder'=>'Tanggal Mulai','autocomplete'=>'off','required'])}}
{{Form::text("tanggal_terakhir",$paket->tanggal_terakhir,['placeholder'=>'Tanggal Akhir','autocomplete'=>'off','required'])}}
{{Form::submit("Submit",["class"=>"btn btn-danger"])}}
{{Form::close()}}
```

This code somehow doesnt give an error. But it doesnt work too. Have any ideas? Newbie in Programming and Laravel here.

Comment: where ur $id..i can't identify anywhere..

Comment: @Harshan that the problem, when i add `$id` in `public function update()` an error appeared, have any idea?
  
  
*edit : the error is `Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\paketcontroller::update()`

Comment: when u click submit buton what is appear browser url..can you show me ?

Comment: You can't add id as a parameter, you need the id of the row to update, without which the update doesn't work and it returns nothing. Does the table `paket` have no other row? does it not have an id?

Comment: @Harshan ok,  first when open the menu the link is :     
1. public/admin/paket , this is where the crud, and if i press edit button the url bar in browser move to :    
2. public/admin/formedit/{id} , this is where my edit form appear, and when i press confirm button, its move to :    
3. public/admin/paket , in this one i doesnt know it move to `admin/prosesedit` first or not.

Comment: @Sandeesh this is the look of my table `paket` http://prntscr.com/f9lyt2

Comment: Can you post all your routes and the edit page controller method

Comment: ok wait i'll update my answer with your info

Comment: @Sandeesh sure, im wait for it ;)

Comment: @vl14b updated my answer. try it out

Comment: @Sandeesh nice, i will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Updated based on your route and controller information.

So here are few things you're doing wrong. Since you haven't posted your routes and controller logic, let me give you an example

Delete the following routes since you already have a resource controller with them.

```
Route::get('formedit/{id}', 'paketcontroller@edit');
Route::post('prosesedit', 'paketcontroller@update');
```

Controller

```
public function update($id) {
    $paket = array(
        'nama' => Input::get('nama'),
        'jumlah_user' => Input::get('jumlah_user'),
        'tanggal_mulai' => Input::get('tanggal_mulai'),
        'tanggal_terakhir' => Input::get('tanggal_terakhir')
    );
    DB::table('paket')->where('id', $id)->update($paket);
    return Redirect::route('paket.index')->with('message','berhasil mengedit data');
}
```

In your view

Change edit link from

```
href="formedit/{{$paket->id}}"
```

to

```
href="paket/edit/{{$paket->id}}"
```

Change

```
{{Form::open(array('url'=>'admin/prosesedit','method'=>'post','charset'=>'utf-8'))}}
```

to

```
{{Form::open(array('route' => array('paket.update', $paket->id), 'method' => 'PATCH', 'charset' => 'utf-8'))}}
```

Comment: Hello, i try it, its doesnt work at first, but its work after i not delete `Route::get('formedit/{id}', 'paketcontroller@edit');`, and not edit `href="formedit/{{$paket->id}}"` . Anyway now, my timestamps (updated_at) doesnt updated. Have an idea?

Comment: @vl14b that might not be related to the update method. Can you check if the timestamps are updating when you manually update?

Comment: do u mean manually in sql? well, it doesnt automatically update when i edit the each field (except the timestamp), except if i edit the timestamp itself manually.             
                     
sorry, bad english, cant explain it very well.

Comment: @vl14b i meant try running a sample update command from another controller to check.

Comment: exactly, this is the only controller i have, beside `create record`. if u want to count `create record` then yes, it automatically updated.

Comment: holla @sandessh, sorry late reply, its work , thanks.